# iOS 11 Open Bluetooth page from my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I have to open bluetooth settings page within my app. In iOS 10 I use this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth"]];
```

But in iOS 11 GM this doesn't work anymore.
Is there a new schema?

Comment: `app-prefs` URLs were never officially supported. You should never have relied on them working.

Comment: any Solution ??